# Modalities for fictitious past: could have, should have, and would have

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, conjunctive, tenses, mood, imperfectum

In English, the pattern [*could/should/would* + *have done*] is used for fictional expressions contrary to the fact, e.g.

> You could have done your work yesterday *(but you have not)*.

How to express such modalities in Latin?

For the *could have done* case, I think of **fecisse potui** which is parallel to the English pattern, but I am not sure of its legality in Latin.

For the *should have done*, a workaround using imperfect subjunctive is given in [this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16728/is-noli-illud-dixisse-good-latin-for-you-should-not-have-said-that). I also consider using a gerundive with **fuit**, but I am not sure if it is legal, either. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if these expressions (“woulda, shoulda, coulda”) look very similar in English, it is probably helpful to look at two things separately:

**Would have** is a true counterfactual, and since the “would have” clause is really the apodosis of a condition contrary to fact in past time, you just do it by the book and use the pluperfect subjunctive. To quote a famous adage:

> Si tacuisses, philosophus manisses.
> *If you had kept silent, you would have remained a philosopher.*

There are a few cases where the indicative is used even though you might say “would have” in English; some of these are not so clear-cut counterfactual conditions:

- The perfect indicative is usually used with *paene* (almost), e.g. *paene dixi*. (This is often explicitly pointed out in grammars written for German speakers. I guess to English speakers it comes naturally.)
- With impersonal phrases expressing some sort of propriety judgement, like: “it would have been better, it would have been just,” etc., the indicative is used: *melius fuit, iustum erat, &c.* This also applies in the present tense: *Longum est omnia enumerare proelia* (Nepos, *Hannibal* 5; thankfully Nepos really spares us a list of all the battles, so this must be translated as: “it would take too long”).
- With negated expressions of belief, like *numquam putavi* (I would never have thought), *melius quam putaveram* (better than I would have thought), and with rhetorical question like *quis umquam putavit?* (Who would ever have thought?)

While German grammars tend to belabour this point quite a bit (for example Hermann Menge [here](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Repetitorium_der_lateinischen_Grammatik/NhsrXnUbsBQC?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PA258&printsec=frontcover)), I could not find much in Allen & Greenough besides [this anodyne little paragraph](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/indicative-mood). This is perhaps due to English being more flexible and closer to Latin with such expressions (“I almost lost my keys,” “I never thought I'd see the day”).

**Could have** and **should have** are not really counterfactual. When I say, “you could have done your work yesterday,” I mean you really were able to. Therefore, while it may give English (and German, and others) speakers a pause, it only makes sense that Latin uses the indicative perfect, imperfect or pluperfect here, e.g. *pensum heri absolvere potuisti*, and similarly: *hoc facere debuisti, faciendum fuit* etc.

According to Menge, you use the perfect and pluperfect to indicate that the situation does not continue to the present or to the time of the narration: *hoc facere potuisti* – you could have done it, but now it's too late; *hoc facere potueras* – you could have done it, but by then it was too late; *hoc facere poteras* – you could have done it already, but you still can.